# Stop clear button from calling viewTapped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Whenever the built in clear button is touched in a UITextField, the method 'viewTapped' is being called. I have some logic in this method that is unwanted behavior when clear is touched.

Is there any way to prevent this? Either all together, or some if statement I can add that will filter out when this method is called from the user touching clear.

Comment: What scenarios do you need this logic to be used on? With that information I might be able to redirect you to another method you can listen into instead.

Comment: Tapping outside of a textfield dismisses the keyboard. The method calls [tableView didEndEditing]

Comment: I would look into the UITextFieldDelegate call `textFieldDidEndEditing` to listen in on when the textfield is no longer the firstResponder (aka keyboard dismissed).  From there you can call [tableView didEndEditing].  Let me know if that works for you and if so I'll make it an answer for future googlers.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my viewTapped method to:

```
- (void)viewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchLocation]];
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(cell.frame, touchLocation) ) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

This properly filtered out times where the method was called from clear being tapped.